# The Workplace and The Great Outdoors seem out of place from dropdown selector

Tags: feature-request

Under the stack exchange bar at the top that contains the list of all sites, currently "The Workplace" and "The Great Outdoors" fall under "T" when alphabetized. This seems very non-intuitive when searching. Perhaps "The Workplace" belongs with the W's and "The Great Outdoors" belongs with the G/O's?

Comment: Are those site names supposed to be code variables? Why do you format like that?

Comment: Dunno, I had them in quotation marks at first but it looked weird. Reverted to quotation marks